# Would mechnical resonance-induced decay affecting only hard supplies from Earth be plausible?

Tags: internal-consistency, materials

The year is 21XX, humans are trying to run away from the hot dumpster Earth has become. Space travel is possible thanks to an accidental tech discovery allowing long-distance jumps in space. The closer and most practical habitable planet in proximity happen to be actually close enough to send multiple ships a month for colonization.

Problem is : there's something in here that makes metal, alloys and any material industrially processed from Earth decay extremely fast. Bigger structures tend to turn to pieces extremely fast, the first spaceships started to fall in pieces quickly hours after landing, our vehicles lasted a week at most, any suit or tools seemed to wear off by itself after some time and were unusable after a month... Without additional supplies we're basically left to live to rebuild and craft everything with materials coming from this planet.

Why would it affect only our hard materials Earth-originating supplies and not living organisms or our fabric clothes ?

Comment: What makes you think that there is a single specific answer to this question? We prohibit open ended, brainstorming, questions like this. Can you try to [edit] this into something more suitable for this site.

Comment: @sphennings Done, hope it's better

Comment: Given that Psi waves are fantastical, we don't know what causes them, or how they work. How do you expect us to be able to answer this question?

Comment: This is what I came up at the moment as a placeholder cause for the rapid decay of Earth-made supplies by withering their internal structure. As the effect is supposed to be faster for large structures, I am tempted to use mechanical resonance as an explanation. The thing is, could an magic external force (psi-whatever) induce a rapid decay of specific materials by messing with said materials mechanical resonance ?

Comment: [edit] anything you want us to consider into the question. If you feel that psi-wave induced mechanical resonance works, you aren't obligated to run worldbuilding ideas by us.  Don't hesitate to just go forth and write!

Comment: If something is magic it can do whatever you want.

Comment: I'm asking Worldbuilding if using mechanical resonance as a reason would make sense or if it could have side-effects I oversaw

Comment: @Oddrigue magic fixes all things; there's nothing you overlooked, because your magic will always do exactly what you needed it to do build your setting and further you plot. "_Mechanical resonance_" may as well be technobabble, and as such I'd avoid it but that's an aesthetic choice.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to remove additional questions. We have a strict one question per post policy on this site.

Comment: @sphennings Sorry I recentered the post to the right problematic following comments

Comment: @Oddrigue, I'd suggest you actually ask what kinds of natural phenomena decay mechanical structures faster than biological ones. You could then model your psi effects on those known mechanisms.

Comment: *"There's something in here that makes metal, alloys and any material industrially processed from Earth decay extremely fast":* The thing is that there is no difference between metal processed on Earth and metal processed anywhere else. The point being that whetever process is discombobulating the metal machines transported from Earth, it will also discombobulate any metal machines built locally. Which means that the colonists won't have any metal machinery. Which means that the planet is unsuitable for colonization. Scratch it off the list and search for a better one.

Comment: @Oddrigue Some important clarifications are required. (a) If an object made of nickle brought from Earth decays, is there nickle on the new planet that does not? (b) Is this only an issue for alloys (e.g., tin)? or does any hard material (metal or not) decay? (c) If alloys are only considered, alloys come in basic forms (bronze, brass, pig iron) or more complex forms (stainless steel)? What if the alloy isn't two metals (e.g., pig iron, iron + carbon)? Please [edit] your question with the clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you're misusing the [tag:internal-consistency] tag. In summary, the tag's purpose is for you to provide a list of world rules and a circumstance to test against those rules. We judge if you're consistently using the rules. That's not what you're doing here. That tag needs to be replaced. I recommend using the [tag:science-fiction] tag.

Comment: For an example of fiction in which something like this happened (somewhat), see [Star Trek Voyager: Course Oblivion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course:_Oblivion). The explanation was that the entire crew and most of the ship/contents were made of a mimetic compound which started to break down. Only items imported were patent.

Answer (score 3):

**Ions**

[image: rusty construction machine]

https://www.visittci.com/north-caicos-middle-caicos/nongatown-landing

You describe oxidative decomposition.  Living in San Diego is like that.  Metals rust.  Rubber gets hard and breaks.  Pencil erasers cease to erase.  Plastics crack.

It is because salt ions suspended in the air electrochemically potentiate the interaction between oxygen and oxidizable substrate.  In your world, psi waves do the same thing: they tend to ionize materials which turns out to mostly be in the atmosphere, and the ionized materials are more reactive.

Oxidation of materials is the most obvious part.  People on this world would become blond and some very blond until they started putting antioxidants in their hair.  And on their skin.  And goggles.  And hopefully they remember charcoal filter nose plugs to protect their poor lungs before they get too wheezy.

There are other aspects too: more ionization means more lightning.  Often at night, everything has St Elmos fire on it - glowy purple corona discharges.  Depending on how big this psi field covers there might be some serious auroras at night.

There might be life forms that sense psi and use it to navigate the environment.

You can still be an anime hottie with goggles and nose plugs, because you are blond (or maybe greenish blond) and you wear anime hottie clothes which are stylishly decomposing off your body.  Also at night you are lit from above by your purple halo of St Elmo's fire which reflects off your goggles.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. OP is asking about why mechanical resonance would only affect machines and not soft things like humans or clothes. Please don't answer questions while OP is actively in the process of resolving issues. Had you posted sooner OP wouldn't have been able to resolve the issues without invalidating your answer and their question would need to be closed.

Comment: The original question asks "why would this effect machines," and that's not a real question. The real question would be "What kind of phenomena would only effect machines." Once that question is answered (which Willk does here), then you can answer why. If this doesn't precisely answer the question, it's because it's a bad question, not because this is a bad answer.

Comment: Why isn't this an answer? Seems to be a darn good answer, at least to the current version of the question, "Why would it affect only our hard materials Earth-originating supplies and not living organisms or our fabric clothes?" Now, if the OP's planet has its own metals that are unaffected, then this wouldn't work (at least not well), but it's likely there isn't an answer short of magic.